# Get id for nested MVC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller, nested

`<%= @dueler.id %>` is showing the wrong integer. For example, duel has two duelers `34` and `35`. The `current_user` is `78`, which dueler `34` is user `78`.

By making sure the `current_user` is a dueler of the duel then he will be empowered to update his dueler status.

**duels/show**

```
Duel <%= @duel.id %> = 20
Dueler <%= @dueler.id %> = 10 # How to get 34 instead?
User <%= current_user.id %> = 78
```

**rails c**

```
pry(main)> Dueler.last
 id: 34, # This is what it should say since 78 is the current_user
 user_id: 78,
 challenge_id: 295,
 duel_id: 20,
 accept: nil>
pry(main)> Dueler.last
 id: 35,
 user_id: 150,
 challenge_id: 290,
 duel_id: 20,
 accept: nil>
pry(main)> Duel.last
 id: 20,
 consequence: "TEST",
 reward: "TEST",
 created_at: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 21:38:31 EDT -04:00,
 updated_at: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 21:38:31 EDT -04:00>
```

**duels_controller**

```
def show
  @duel = Duel.find(params[:id])
  @duelers = Duel.duelers.find(params[:id]) # What should this be instead?
end
```

I thought maybe something like this would work:

```
def show
  @duel = Duel.find(params[:id])
  @duelers = Duel.duelers.find(params[:id]) # Get hash of duelers i.e. 34 & 35
  @dueler = @duelers.find(current_user = Dueler.user_id) # If current_user is equal to the user_id of dueler then that dueler is thee dueler, i.e. 34
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In duels_controller

```
def show
  @duel = Duel.find(params[:id])  ##params[:id] should be 20
  @dueler = @duel.duelers.find_by(user_id: current_user) ##it will return first dueler of duel which is 34 for the user: 78. in the given example. 
end
```

In show method view:

```
Duel <%= @duel.id %> = 20
Dueler <%= @dueler.id %> = 34 
User <%= current_user.id %> = 78
```

Comment: `where(user_id: current_user).first` can be written as `find_by(user_id: current_user)`